# Reading data from an input file and placing the data in appropriate fields in an xml

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, xml

I have a input file and an xml file.

input file-

```
/user/sht
227_89,45_99
/user/sht1
230_90
/user/sht2
441_50
```

The file has alternate lines containing path and position.

xml file-

```xml
<aaa><command name="move">
<domain>
<path></path>
<positions></positions>
</domain>
<domain>
<path></path>
<positions></positions>
</domain>
<domain>
<path></path>
<positions></positions>
</domain>
</command>
</aaa>
```

I need to write a script to give the below output xml required and then run some commands using the below xml as input-

```xml
<aaa><command name="move">
<domain>
<path>/user/sht</path>
<positions>227_89,45_99</positions>
</domain>
<domain>
<path>/user/sht1</path>
<positions>230_90</positions>
</domain>
<domain>
<path>/user/sht2</path>
<positions>441_50</positions>
</domain>
</command>
</aaa>
```

I have tried extracting line by line from the input file and placing it in the xml, but the issue is that every occurrence of `<path>` is replaced by the first input line.

Using GNU bash 4.1.2.

Comment: bash is a shell, not a text editor

Comment: @JeffSchaller Sorry I didn't specify, I need to write a script which performs the above. The script also uses the output xml as input for a command, but this is not in the scope of the question.

Comment: **note that xml (as well as html) is not obligatory structure with "1 tag per 1 line"** - it could have multiple different tags on one line. In that case, all sed solutions been posted won't work

Comment: @Philippos, The question clearly says: "*I have a input file and an **xml** file*". And xml files are those  files that I have described in my previous comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a single GNU `sed` script you could do something like

```
sed -n '/<aaa>/,/<.aaa>/!{H;d}
G;:a
s_>\(</path>.*\n\)\n\([^\n]*\)_>\2\1_
s_>\(</positions>.*\n\)\n\([^\n]*\)_>\2\1_;
ta;P;s/.*\n\n/\n/;h' input.txt input.xml
```

The first line collects all lines from the first file in the hold buffer.

Then for each line of the second file the hold buffer is appended with `G`. If it's a `path` or `positions` the first segment of the hold buffer is moved insides the tags with one of the two `s` commands.

In any case the line is printed (`P`) and removed (`s/.*\n\n/\n/`) and what's left of the replace list is moved back to the hold buffer for the next cycle (`h`).

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU sed and the format for XML as shown:

```
sed -e '
   /<domain>/,/<\/domain>/!b
   /<\(path\|positions\)><\/\1>/!b
   s//<\1>/
   R input_file
' XML_file |
sed -e '
   /<\(path\|positions\)>.*/N
   s//&\n<\/\1>/
   s/\n//g
'
```

---

### Results

```
<aaa><command name="move">
<domain>
<path>/user/sht</path>
<positions>227_89,45_99</positions>
</domain>
<domain>
<path>/user/sht1</path>
<positions>230_90</positions>
</domain>
<domain>
<path>/user/sht2</path>
<positions>441_50</positions>
</domain>
</command>
</aaa>
```

Answer (score 0):

Shell script which will cover your requirement

```
#!/bin/bash
count=0          ## counting lines
while read var
do
    occurance=$[$count/2+1];                  ## check nth occurance of search path/position from file
if [ $((count%2)) -eq 0 ];                ## If counting even replace path values else replace position values
then
    perl -pe 's{<path>*}{++$n == '$occurance' ? "<path>'$var'" : $&}ge' xml > xml1
else
    perl -pe 's{<positions>*}{++$n == '$occurance' ? "<positions>'$var'" : $&}ge' xml > xml1
fi
yes|cp xml1 xml
    count=$[$count +1]
done <./input
rm xml1
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that XML (as well as HTML) is not an obligatory structure with ***"1 tag per 1 line"*** - it could have ***multiple*** different tags on ***one*** line.

In such case, I would suggest ***Python*** solution:

***fill_xml.py*** script:

```
import collections, xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('yourxmlfile.xml') # <- specify your actual xml file name
root = tree.getroot()

with open('input.txt', 'r') as f:
    d = collections.defaultdict(list)
    for k,l in enumerate(f.read().splitlines()):
        if k % 2 == 0:  # treating each 2nd line as `positions` value
            d['path'].append(l)
        else:
            d['positions'].append(l)

    # iterating through `path`/`positions` node pairs
    for k, nodes in enumerate(zip(root.findall('.//path'), root.findall('.//positions'))):
        nodes[0].text = d['path'][k]        # setting `path` value
        nodes[1].text = d['positions'][k]   # setting `positions` value
    tree.write('result.xml')                # write to the result file
```

***Usage***:

```
python fill_xml.py
```

The `result.xml` contents:

```
<aaa><command name="move">
<domain>
<path>/user/sht</path>
<positions>227_89,45_99</positions>
</domain>
<domain>
<path>/user/sht1</path>
<positions>230_90</positions>
</domain>
<domain>
<path>/user/sht2</path>
<positions>441_50</positions>
</domain>
</command>
</aaa>
```

Answer (score 0):

In shell :

```
echo '<aaa><command name="move">'
echo '<domain>'

while true
do read v || break
   echo "<path>$v</path>"
   read v || break
   echo "<positions>$v</positions>"
done < /path/to/YourInputFile

echo '</domain>
</command>
</aaa>'
```